# Как изменить цвет надписи на StackPanel?

Tags: wpf, xaml, color

```
<Popup StaysOpen="False">

    <Border   BorderBrush="#000000" BorderThickness="1">
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
        </Border.Background>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

            <CheckBox Background="#000000" Foreground="#FFFFFF"/>
            <CheckBox Background="#000000" Foreground="#FFFFFF"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

Comment: Уже сделано. `<CheckBox Background="#000000" Foreground="#FFFFFF"/>`

Comment: Уже вопрос решён: `Foreground="#FFFFFF"`